# How to speed up loading Angular JS project built with Gulp on the server?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp

I created a web application using AngularJS and GulpJS.
It calls some REST links and get data. ERP like system.
And I built that using "gulp serve:dist" and hosted those release files on the server. Here's the link to the hosted application.
http://138.197.118.115/stockmanager

The problem is it takes a lot of time to load. In locally it's not taking a long time. there's a progress bar and it's appearing more that 40 seconds sometimes. I think that's because of some gulp issue.

Can anyone suggest me a solution. I created this system using https://github.com/akveo/blur-admin template.

This is my gulpfile.js
https://github.com/akveo/blur-admin/blob/master/gulpfile.js

And these are the other files related to Gulp.
https://github.com/akveo/blur-admin/tree/master/gulp

Comment: @Soviut I added those files. Please check